# lscpu shows me "op-mode:32-bit, 64-bit", what it means?

Tags: architecture

`lscpu` outputs me this information: `CPU op-mode(s):  32-bit, 64-bit`
Does this mean my Ubuntu is running under 32 or 64 bits processor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running lspcu shows you that your processor supports both 32 and 64 bit instructions.

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

But this is just about the CPU.

Next, run `uname -p`

If you see output like this:

```
x86_64
```

then you are running a 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

```
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
```

It means your CPU supports both 32 bit and 64 bit instructions.